# Calculating the complexity of an algorithm exercises

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, books

I am really bad at calculating correctly the complexity of a given algorithm. I would like to know if there is some book or online resources where I can find many exercises that ask to calculate the complexity of a given algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: Not from my perspective.  That one's very complicated, even the example of a little FOR/NEXT loop. Perhaps we could have something easier to follow..?